# unexpected behaviour of debounce() operator in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-binding

I am using `RxBinding` to validate form inputs.

the problem is when I try to use the `debounce()` operator as below the app misbehaves, it does not crash but the app restarts just after I open the activity that calls `setupForm()`  **without showing any sign of crashing.**

when I remove the `debounce()` it works perfectly.

here is my code.

```
 private void setupForm() {

    Observable<Boolean> itemNameObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(tilItemName.getEditText()).
            map(text -> (text.toString().length() > 6))
            .distinctUntilChanged();

    itemNameObservable.subscribe(valid -> {

        tilItemName.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_itemNam));
        tilItemName.setErrorEnabled(!valid);

    });


    Observable<Boolean> descObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(tilItemDescription.getEditText()).
            map(text -> (text.toString().length() > 6))
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .distinctUntilChanged();

    descObservable.subscribe(valid -> {
        tilItemDescription.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_description));
        tilItemDescription.setErrorEnabled(!valid);

    });


    Observable<Boolean> cityObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(tilFinderCity.getEditText()).
            map(text -> (text.toString().length() > 6))
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .distinctUntilChanged();

    cityObservable.subscribe(valid -> {

        tilFinderCity.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_city));
        tilFinderCity.setErrorEnabled(!valid);

    });


    Observable<Boolean> phoneObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(tilFinderPhone.getEditText()).
            map(text -> (text.toString().length() > 6))
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .distinctUntilChanged();

    phoneObservable.subscribe(valid -> {
        tilFinderPhone.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_phone));
        tilFinderPhone.setErrorEnabled(!valid);

    });


    //combine all value from inputs and (&&) them. add button is enabled if all are set
    Observable.combineLatest(
            itemNameObservable
            , descObservable
            , cityObservable,
            phoneObservable
            , (itemNameIsValid, descIsValid, cityIsValid, phoneIsValid) -> (cityIsValid && descIsValid && phoneIsValid && itemNameIsValid))
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(shouldEnable -> btnAddItem.setEnabled(shouldEnable));


    RxView.clicks(btnAddItem)
            .subscribe(view -> presnter.addItem(getItemFromForm()));


}
```

Comment: Does it restart the very first time you call `setupForm()`?

Comment: I am putting `setupForm()`  inside `onCreate()`, so when I open this specific activity the app restarts immediately.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem space. Start by removing all but one of the observables, and removing the first subscription. You could also supply an explicit scheduler to the `debounce()` operator, and ensure that there is an unhandled exception handler set for that scheduler.

Comment: Most likely unrelated, but considering that the mapping might be expensive, I'd put the `debounce()` first in the chain, just before the `map()`. Also your first subscription to every observable could be a side effect with `doOnNext()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The `debounce` operator operates by default on the `computation` scheduler, that's why your app crashes. 
You can verify that by taking a look at the logs, you'll see something like this `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

The solution is to add this line `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` right after the `debounce()` call.

Answer (score 0):

When using RxTextView.textChanges, remember that during subscribe, it will immediately emit a result, so you have to take that into account. Either it can not affect your code, or you can do something like .skip(1)

I think with the debounce you should include a backpressure strategy as well, so try something like:

```
Observable<Boolean> phoneObservable = 
RxTextView.textChanges(tilFinderPhone.getEditText())
            .map(text -> (text.toString().length() > 6))
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            .distinctUntilChanged();
```

which will:

```
/**
 * Keeps only the latest onNext value, overwriting any previous value if the
 * downstream can't keep up.
 */
```